# Android - running background tasks that can fail

Tags: android, concurrency

I need to be able to cancel tasks involving web requests. 
but I got some issues of memory management and exception handling when something fail. 
For example:

I want to create a text edit for searching apps in user device.

so whenever user end a key, I want to clear current search task, and restart search.

The problem I got is in android 4.4, when trying to load the label of the app (to get it's name) I get an exception.

Also of I try to search contacts I'm getting an invlalid uri, fo rcontact photo.

I don't want any help dealing with this errors, I want a solution that will help me ignore this erros (try catach dont work) currently the entire ui get's stuck and app crash.
I'm using the executors service and call cancel when user gives me an input. but it's not enough.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: retard comment from a noob, sry : if I were in your situation and after posting to SO, I would try to copy the mechanisms of Volley API since the code is opened.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using AsyncTask i would like to suggest you to make it like this

```
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> a = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

    };
    a.execute();

    // at some point you want to cancel just use
    a.cancel(true);
```

You can even put tasks together in List or array and loop to cancel it whenever you want.

Comment: I'm not but maybe I should.. I'm calling the UI handler post method to sync with ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: what you want is getting result in background by network and show result in view ,you can Register a Listener to one task,. you can callback method of listener to use show  result in view if it get the results in background ,if you do not need the result of current task and want satrt the next task ,you can only remove listener of current task,so the view will not reload

This is my idea ,I am so sorry for my bad english , if you do not see ,you can send message to me, and my email is bjltxsp@gmail.com